# Win10 ignoring AAAA responses

Tags: ipv6, windows-10

Despite having a valid IPv6 address and being able to communicate with other IPv6 hosts, a Windows 10 system on my LAN is igonring AAAA responses and as such will not initiate IPv6 traffic.

- `nslookup` will show the A record for a domain, but not the AAAA record, even though I can see in Wireshark that the AAAA query is sent and a valid response is received.
- Reverse `nslookup` works as expected and if I query an IPv6 address I get back the expected hostname.
- `ping -6` works when I go directly to another IPv6 address, but not when I enter a hostname. This is likely an artifact of the ignored AAAA response mentioned above.
- IPv4 works as expected.
- Dual-stack Linux and BSD systems on the same subnet with the same nameserver work as expected.

I found this (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users) about preferring IPv4 over IPv6, but I do not have those registry keys set.

Edit: Does it matter that my nameservers only listen on IPv4?

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Users\John> nslookup -type=AAAA google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::d66e:eff:fe35:c5d4

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Address:  2607:f8b0:4009:80e::200e
```

Without a type parameter, nslookup will return A record if one exists. I assume that is for compatibility because someone relies on the default behavior.

(I found nslookup's usage message and online documentation useless. At least [type examples are available from third parties](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/nslookup-checking-dns-records-on-windows/).)

Comment: This does not work for me: `can't find www.google.com: Not implemented`

Comment: What nslookup command are you running? In a packet capture what queries do you see on the wire?

Comment: ```>nslookup www.google.com 1.1.1.1
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Address:  172.217.15.100```

Comment: Everything works as expected when adding an IPv6 nameserver. It seems that Windows does not support AAAA over v4, only A over v4 and AAAA over v6.

Comment: I get IPv6 addresses just fine from several public DNS services over v4.  `-type=AAAA` seems to be required.